# Which editor for coding in Borland C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, borland-c++

I have a 64 bit OS (Windows 7). I want to code in C++ but the default editor of Borland does not support full screen mode on my system. Which editor do i use to solve this problem?
I want to code in Turbo C++ only.

Comment: Do you mean Borland C++?  As for the editor, just use one you like.

Comment: It really is time to ditch that 25 year old compiler and IDE and use something a little more modern and standards-compliant.

Comment: You do mean Borland, right? And why in tarnation would you want to use Borland when there are so many excellent, modern and free C++ IDEs out there? Just download VC++ 2010 Express Edition and be done with it.

Comment: ok, i will not use bodland c++ but VC++ is a totally different ball game. Which compiler for c++ do i use? Any recommendations?

Comment: VC++ comes with the Microsoft compiler, editor, debugger and so on. There's nothing to configure. It might be a different ball game, but that is a good thing because Borland is really dated.

Comment: Borland is no longer supporting its compilers.  Its compiler does not take advantage of Windows 7 or 64-bit platforms.  You might as well use a modern compiler with a modern platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use netbeans-IDE 6.0.. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup DosBox.
2. Install Borland C in DosBox environment.
3. Launch bin\bc.exe

Dosbox allows you to make fullscreen window